# Two backgrounds upon each other with CSS

Tags: css

I have a div that i want to apply two backgrounds to it. Basically I have one small picture that will be repeated all over the div, and another big one (no repeats). 
I tried to make two divs of the same size layed one upon the other and here is the CSS code it works but I want to do it in a more fashionable way.

```
.science_wrap{
background-image: url(../bg/graph-paper-background.png);
width:100%;
height: 694px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

```
.science {
background-image: url(../bg/prospectus-science-line.png);
width:100%;
height: 694px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

Also, i have another div which will have one strip on the top (i have a bg image for it) and I want to put upon it another picture, any tips or tricks to do this?

Comment: What's your HTML look like?  Also, you're not applying no-repeat to the image.

Comment: I think that is the best way to get what you achieve. But i will be interested on what others have to say.

Comment: Overlapping div's is the best solution currently, with css3's multiple backgrounds growing in value as IE dies a fiery death as per @Oliver below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

css3 has provision for multiple backgrounds:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-background-20050216/#layering

However, older browsers do not support css3. In particular, IE8 and below do not support it - IE9 does.

You can use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) to force support for css3 in older versions of IE, but it can be a little slow, and has some bugs.

If you need to support IE6 it is best to continue using your existing method, I think.

**EDIT:**

The syntax will look something like this:

```
background-image: url(../bg/graph-paper-background.png), url(../bg/prospectus-science-line.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
```

Comment: But how is it possible to layer them without using another div?

Comment: @MohamedTurki Did you read his answer? Multiple backgrounds, a single div.

Comment: @MohamedTurki See my edit. Have just one element `.science` and give it the css for multiple backgrounds that I have written above. Remember that this will not work in older versions of Internet Explorer unless you use css3pie.

Answer (score 1):

You can use psuedo elements like :after or :before to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/JUsXx/

Or you can use CSS3 multiple backgrounds: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ (live example: http://jsfiddle.net/JUsXx/1/)

Comment: @ANeves I know. But I couldn't find another transperant picture.

Comment: Something must have changed. Neither of the above fiddles seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Pseudo's :before and :after will help you here. They are also more compatible than CSS3's multiple backgrounds.

```
.science_wrap {
   background-image: url(../bg/graph-paper-background.png);
   width:100%;
   height: 694px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.science_wrap:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    background-image: url(../bg/prospectus-science-line.png);
    width:100%;
    height: 694px;
}
```